# Issue when adding the row at the bottom of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview

Add(), Insert() methods add the item before not after the last row

I have problem as I try to add the row to the DataGridView.

I can of course can manually rearrange the collection but i do not believe that there is no method to add the item after the all elements.

As after I understand new element to have index larger than all other elements.

Sorry for the images - but it easier for me to show what happens

Before:
[image]
After[image]

As you see the row is added *before* the previous one - not after

[image]
The row is before the old one.

Comment: Can you please provide an [mcve] of what you are talking about? What kind of item source do you use for the `DataGridView`? Do you add the items directly or via binding to a `ObservableCollection` or any other collection? I'm sure that e.g. `List<T>.Add()` inserts the item at the end of the list. Note that the **list content** maybe sorted differently than how it is **viewed** by the `DataGridView`.

Comment: _Add().. method add the item before not after the element with the index._ No, it doesn't. Add has no index and will append at the end.

Comment: Maybe DataGridView has overwirtten this method. I see in my debugger that the added row has index lower than the previous one.

Comment: @P__J__ I really wonder how a 6k user expects us to help him/her with code we can't see. Without a mcve, we don't know what you are talking about. You confuse _rows_ and _items_, _collections_ and _views_ etc...Please try to clarify your question and make it clear what _exactly_ the problem is. A `DataGridView` is a complex control that automatically supports sorting, filtering, grouping etc.. I'm currently working with one, and it displays newly added rows at the correct position according to the _current sorting column_.

Comment: @RenéVogt As it is only one line of code `.Add()`. And it is added before. And the inserted row is displayed on top the old one.. See my amended question.

Comment: @TaW But it actually does in this collection

Comment: Where is the List in those images?

Comment: I think __you are confusing the actual rows__ with the __automatic row__ which will __always show at the end__ when you have `dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows == true`. Set it to `false` while you are using code to add rows and sanity comes back ;-)

Comment: @TaW Post is the answer and will accept it as the answer. Thank you

Comment: BTW 4 close votes & 3 downvotes - you are very nervous guys :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking real close at the image one can see that the row at end has an ***asterisk*** in the header.

This is the indicator that it is **a new row with changes**. (Before the changes it has a ***pen*** image.)

This **new, automatic row** is always displayed **at the end** because users expect to add rows there.

While you are adding rows in code, you may not want this; so simply set

```
view.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

and all is well.

Also: Make it a habit to take the return from `Add()` and use that index to work with the new row. With this small change your issue wouldn't have come up.